# Accidentally plugged 6+2 PCIe into ATX 12V port, is everything damaged?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply

I haven't done a build in a long time and today just plugged the 6+2 PCIe into the ATX 12V port (why, given the simplicity of keying these plugs of this format, especially when a mistake can lead to damage, is this even possible??) – Power supply is a `Fractal Newton R3 800W`, motherboard is a `Gigabyte GA-Z97N-WIFI`, CPU is an `Intel i7 4790k`.

I finished the build and switched it on for the first time. The CPU fan spun up once or twice then the system turned off.

I realized my mistake and now connected the appropriate cable from the modular set.

Now the system won't power up at all, ***is anything permanently damaged or is it likely to be localized to one component?*** *(please please don't say CPU)*

I'm surprised neither the PSU nor Motherboard manuals mentioned anything about how serious this mistake could be with any kind of warning. All it said was "Without the ATX12v cable plugged in, the system will not start"

Comment: I would try another PSU before condemning the motherboard

Comment: Hm ok, I went and grabbed another power supply, no luck... I'll have to get another motherboard and see. Such a shame, really truly hoping that the damage wasn't so far as to ruin the CPU, RAM and everything else. Oddly enough there wasn't even a single hint of a smoky smell from either the PSU nor the motherboard.

Comment: unplug all hardware from the mobo except the psu, processor and one memory module, see if anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to give a definite answer, but the fact that your system now does not power up at all suggests that the motherboard has suffered damage.

As for the other components, you'll have to test them with known-good hardware to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely you fried either your motherboard or PSU, both which could mean other components in your PC are likely to have been fried too. The pin outs on the connectors are totally different, and it will have shorted instantly.

Your best bet is to unplug the PC, hold down the power button to drain the capacitors and then try again and hope it damaged nothing.

You could look at your motherboard to try and identify burnt areas but i think it's going to be a case of testing each component to find which are faulty and hope it's only your PSU.